# hide UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, hide, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

hy

I have an UITabBarController relied to 5 UiViewControllers, so my UiTabBar has 5 items. I want to just hide the last item from the bar and note remove it. 
(the tab must still accessible programmatically with myUItabBarController.selectedIndex=4; for example )

it's possible?

thanks

Comment: So you only want to hide the last button in your tabbar?

Comment: is not more simple.. to remove it from UITabBarController? Can be accessible "modal": [[self presentViewController:your5Controller animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: thx TonyMkenu. to solve my problem I use now UiTabBar without UITabBarController and it's not more necessary for me to hide any item.
Using UiTabBar without Controller : 
http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/ios-dev-add-tabbar-to-a-view-without-a-tabbarcontroller/
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2099944?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with this : 
http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/ios-dev-add-tabbar-to-a-view-without-a-tabbarcontroller/